# maven dependency version if not found try with other version

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

Can I use maven dependency with 2 versions?
E.g. - try with first dependency, if not found then try with next one...

I think this is not possible with maven range.

Example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.x</groupId>
    <artifactId>ae.zt</artifactId>
    <version>12.1_bugfix_AE-12, 12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here it should first try with version 2.1_bugfix_AE-12, and only if the version was not found it should try with version 12.1.

Comment: Check this out  - http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/resolve-ranges.html

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible with Maven.

I wonder: Which problem do you want to solve? If 12.1 is "good enough", why use the other one?

Furthermore, any automatism would mean that you do not really know which version was included.

Comment: @nullpointer Version ranges are still supported in Maven 3.5.0. They are not recommended, though.

Comment: @nullpointer Maybe I misunderstand a thing but what brings you to this conclusion? I'm not aware of such thing...as JF Meier already wrote version ranges are supported and yes they are not recommended...

Comment: @khmarbaise My bad there. Agreed that the support is still there, but not recommended.